# What's up with Stack Overflow ads?

Tags: discussion, advertising

I just reloaded the question page on Stack Overflow and I saw this:

[image]

**Boom!**  A giant horizontal banner ad right in my face.

Up until this point, the ads on Stack Overflow all seemed to be very low key.  I have seen job advertisements and occasional services, but they were always off to the side and out of plain view.

Is this the beginning of the commercialization of Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange?  Will the Biblical Hermeneutics site start selling water from the Sea of Galilee?

What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Looks like you were logged out momentarily (no user info in the top bar). We've shown banner ads to anonymous and low-reputation users for quite a long time. The [reduced ads privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads) is gained at 200 reputation and removes the banner ads from the question pages.

Comment: You are completely correct.  I think the logout occurred, ironically, when I was switching to another Stack Exchange site (either OS Meta or Physical Fitness).  I don't know if this is a bug.